# Get Logs on Device

Tags: android, logging

I need to print logs ( I have added in my application) on real devices. I am using [Alogcat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat&hl=en) 
but it is not showing the logs that i have added in my application. Does any one have any idea how to get logs of application. Other than crash report I need to get the logs of specific code portion to get detail info, tried many application but unable to get logs.

Comment: You should be able to see the logs in Eclipse if your device connected to ADB. Or do you mean you want to see the logs without connecting your device to PC?

Comment: yes the second scenario need to get logs while devices is not connected to Machine

Answer (score 1):

Try to implement DeployeeGate sdk in your project and get log report.

https://deploygate.com/docs/sdk

---

Download deploygate apk in your mobile phone .and install your apk through deploygate apk.

Comment: implement it but not getting Logs in dash board do i need to upload my apk also ?

Comment: ok ..  export your apk and check it  -- check android manifest file debug permission  .i am successfully implemented sdk and use it .